# Is it possible to configure optical trackpad (trackball) to switch on the phone just like iPhone?

Tags: htc-desire, buttons

I find the power button hard to press with one hand. Pressing an optical trackpad (trackball) would be much more convenient. Are there any hacks for this?

Comment: are you referring to "waking up from sleep" or "turning on from shutdown"? If it's the latter, I believe you'd need to at least hack the phone's firmware (assuming htc does not hardwire the power on logic); the former should be trivial.

Comment: At least waking up from sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think turning on from shutdown is not possible without messing with the hardware.  I have a nexus one which is basically the HTC desire and using cyanogen mod i've been able to use the trackball to wake from sleep etc.  You will need to root etc and probably will void your warranty whatsoever.

Try the following link for more info:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=690477

also google  cyanogen mod (i can only post one link at a time)

Comment: Also check http://www.absolutelyandroid.com/trackball-wake-up-for-nexus-one/ for some applications in the market which do not require rooting.